# An unexpected packet was received before the handshake. - Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, mobile-application

When I run the `Flutter` project on `Android Studio`, before running the application on the emulator, the event log displays `"An unexpected packet was received before the handshake"` for `six` to `seven` times. After that, the application runs properly on the emulator.  
But when I run the same project on `VS Code`, it works fine.

**Note:** I also make `Java` applications on Android Studio and it never displayed this error.

Answer (score 0):

go to emulator tab.
click check for updates.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]

Comment: It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Kotlin, make sure it's updated. It must be 1.5.31 or greater according to docs.flutter.dev. In android studio, go to Tools > Kotlin > Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates.

Comment: I've the latest version (1.6.21).